# Add specific content for each client in the account area woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with bootstrap theme in wordpress and using woocomerce to manage the online store, I'm trying to display especific content for every client, I know that woocomerce display some espefic information But is not enought. For example: If one client bought a red car and other client bought a blue car, How can I display a new tab to the client that bought a red car, with especific information like a special offer for the next purchase or personal invitation to access an especial event.
I was thinking that I can create a custom template for those especific client and insert in the client area in a new tab, but I don't know how can I do this. I apreciate any idea or help, thanks in advance.